# How to share value between all component in react

Tags: reactjs, components

Im creating a popup that will be shown to the user after login. He should select an option that will be shared in all components as prop. Everytime this popup is open and the value change, all the component should be updated. Do you have any tips on how I should do it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way would be using redux or context to have global state that can be shared with all of your components. I do not know your app volume and component numbers but if you are looking for a basic way for basic app, you can set this popup states in parent component of your app and pass this state as props to your children components. Another way would be implementing this with backend that you can do post request each time when you change your popup data and do get request in your children components

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I choose Redux and It works well